# Преобразования различных типов данных

Tags: c, типы-данных

Я новичок на Си и пытаюсь создать аналог словоря, и столкнулся с проблемой типизации.
Мой словарь умеет создовать *ключ-значение* только для *const char*, я захотел расширить программу, что бы она могла так же использовать значения и других типов данных, попробовал использовать указатель на void, но проблема осталась и у меня появилось несколько вопросов:

**Можно ли сделать так что бы функция преобразовывала в словарь разные типы данных?**

**Как я могу это сделать?**

Основной код:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAXSIZE 5000

struct base
{
    uint8_t *up;
    uint8_t size;
};

typedef struct
{
    base key[MAXSIZE];
    base data[MAXSIZE];
    uint8_t index;
} dict_t;

static uint8_t sizeVal (const char *val);

static dict_t *init (uint8_t s_key, uint8_t s_data)
{
    dict_t *dict;

    dict = (dict_t *) malloc(sizeof(dict_t));
    dict -> key -> up = (uint8_t *) malloc(s_key);
    dict -> data -> up = (uint8_t *) malloc(s_data);

    dict -> key -> size = s_key;
    dict -> data -> size = s_data;
    dict -> index = 1;

    return dict;
}

dict_t *newDict (const char *key, const char *data)
{
    dict_t *dict;
    uint8_t s_key;
    uint8_t s_data;

    s_key = sizeVal(key);
    s_data = sizeVal(data);

    dict = init(s_key, s_data);

    memcpy(dict -> key, key, s_key);
    memcpy(dict -> data, data, s_data);

    return dict;
}

void printDict (dict_t *dict)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < dict -> index; i++)
    {
        fwrite(dict -> key, sizeof(uint8_t), dict -> key -> size, stdout);
        fwrite(": ", sizeof(char), 2, stdout);
        fwrite(dict -> data, sizeof(uint8_t), dict -> data -> size, stdout);
    }
}

static uint8_t sizeVal (const char *val)
{
    uint8_t size;

    for (size = 0; *val != '\0'; val++)
    {
        size++;
    }

    return size;
}
```

Функция main:

```
#include "dict.c"

int main ()
{
    dict_t *dict;

    dict = newDict("key", "data\n");
    printDict(dict);

    return 0;
}
```

Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Разные типы в список можно положить только по указателю с указателем номера типа элемента.

```
struct baseString
{
    uint8_t *up;
    uint8_t size;
};

struct baseDoubleVector
{
    double * up ;
    uint8_t size ;
} ;

enum { TypeString , TypeDoubleVector } ;

typedef struct {
  void * ptr ;
  int type ;
} virtualBase ;

typedef struct
{
    base key[MAXSIZE];
    virtualBase data [ MAXSIZE ] ;
    uint8_t index;
} dict_t ;
```

Нужно будет писать на каждый тип свои функции добавления. А для удобства использования можно попробовать `_Generic`. *(Аналог функции с одним названием , но с разными типами.)*

Или в шаблонном стиле так :

```
# define AddDict( T ) AddDict_##T

dict_t * AddDict ( baseString ) ( const char *key , baseString * ) ;
dict_t * AddDict ( baseDoubleVector ) ( const char *key , baseDoubleVector * ) ;
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, только у меня ещё один очень глупый вопрос, как я могу определять к какому типу данных относится входной элемент, заранее спасибо.

Comment: поле `type` - непонято ?

Comment: А всё наконец то дошло, большое спасибо, что объяснили.